# Error in R yaImpute: cannot use AsciiGridImpute function (kNN, GBM)

Tags: r, knn, qgis, gbm

I am working with remote sensing (Landsat 5 30-m resolution imageries) and wanna estimate forest tree biomass using Landsat bands' reflectance and vegetation indexes as X-predictors and set of ground-based measures of biomass as Y-output. I built kNN model in `yaImpute` package (R) and using same data - ensemble boosting model in package `gbm` (R).

Now I want to draw a raster map of that. Functions `AsciiGridImpute()` (for `yai` objects) and `AsciiGridPredict()` (for other objects like GBM) must help. But I obtained an error.

At first, I have `yai`-object with model and `impute` object with observed and predicted values:

```
test_yai <- yai(x = x_center_raw_imp, y = center_knn_raw_imp$dead, k = 10, method = "randomForest")

test_impute <- impute(test_yai, ancillaryData = center_knn_raw_imp$dead)
```

yai object was built on the 10 variables:

```
Coastal, Blue, Green, Red, NIR, SWIR1, SWIR2, NDVI, IPVI, GRVI
```

For `AsciiGridImpute()` function I need list of x-variables, list with output file and model.
So, having raster object with my satellite imagery, I make ascii files at first.

```
names(Oster_GEE_mask) <- c("Coastal", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "NIR", "SWIR1", "SWIR2", "NDVI", "IPVI", "GRVI") # name layers of raster object as variables in yai object, i.e. kNN model
writeRaster(Oster_GEE_mask[[1]], filename = "Coastal.asc", format="ascii")
```

Etc. So I have written ascii files for all 10 variables. Then

```
xfiles <- list(Coastal = "Coastal.asc", Blue = "Blue.asc", Green = "Green.asc",
               Red = "Red.asc", NIR = "NIR.asc", SWIR1 = "SWIR1.asc",
               SWIR2 = "SWIR2.asc", NDVI = "NDVI.asc", IPVI = "IPVI.asc",
               GRVI = "GRVI.asc") # list of my variables
outfiles <- list(dead = "dead.asc") # as I predicted "dead" column in my yai object, I named output file in same way
```

And function for creating raster map:

```
AsciiGridImpute(test_yai, xfiles, outfiles)
```

But here is an error!

```
    Rows per dot:  12  Rows to do: 1281 
ToDo: ..........................................................................................................
Done: Error in rownames<-(`*tmp*`, value = saveNames) : 
  attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions
```

Set of variables for yai object is the same to names in my x-files. What could be wrong?
(with gbm object I got same error, using `AsciiGridPredict()` instead)

Answer (score 0):

I had to read Crookston et al. (2008) first...

```
AsciiGridImpute(test_yai, xfiles, outfiles, ancillaryData = x_center_raw_imp) # while I tried first to use object 'impute' as ancillaryData instead of reference file with all variables...
```

However, I have trouble with implementing `gbm()` function in `AsciiGridPredict()`. Here I will not find a solution, seemingly, scientists need to be asked...